# two points with same tangent line

Tags: calculus

curve $y=\sin(x)−x/2+10$.
 The slopes of the tangent lines of this function are the same for any two points that are separated by a distance of $2\pi$. Find the two points $(x_0,f(x_0))$ and $(x_0+2\pi,f(x_0+2\pi))$ with $0< x_0<2$ whose tangent lines are the same line.

as much as i can calculated I got, that the slope of tangent line is equal to the derivative of $y$, therefore $= \cos x -1/2 = -1/2$
how should i find the points?
$y(x_0)=\pi/2-9.5$

$y(x_0+2\pi)=(\pi+19)/2\pi$ or $19/2\pi$?

i was confused here.

could anyone help me please, any help would be appreciated

Comment: The two contact points have the same $y$, so the common tangent is horizontal and $\cos(x)=1/2$.

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have $y'=\cos x-\frac 12$, the tangent line at $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is $$y-f(x_0)=\left(\cos x_0-\frac 12\right)(x-x_0),$$i.e.$$y=\left(\cos x_0-\frac 12\right)x+f(x_0)-x_0\left(\cos x_0-\frac 12\right)$$
and the tangent line at $(x_0+2\pi,f(x_0+2\pi))$ is
$$y-f(x_0+2\pi)=\left(\cos(x_0+2\pi)-\frac 12\right)(x-(x_0+2\pi)),$$i.e.$$ y=\left(\cos x_0-\frac 12\right)x+f(x_0+2\pi)-(x_0+2\pi)\left(\cos x_0-\frac 12\right).$$
Since these two lines are the same, we have
$$f(x_0)-x_0\left(\cos x_0-\frac 12\right)=f(x_0+2\pi)-(x_0+2\pi)\left(\cos x_0-\frac 12\right),$$
i.e.
$$\cos x_0=0.$$
So, $x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$.
From $0\lt x_0\lt 2$, we have $k=0$, so $x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: $ \cos x = 0 , x = (2 k -1) \pi/2 $

Comment: @Narasimham: Thank you for your comment. I should have added something like what you wrote.

Comment: does it mean that _x= -π/2_?

Comment: then, i have to put my x to initial equation, right?

Comment: @Sarah: Yes, but note that $x_0=\pi/2$, not $x$. What we want to know is $(x_0,f(x_0))$ and $(x_0+2\pi,f(x_0+2\pi))$. So, all we need to know is $x_0$ to know both $f(x_0)$ and $f(x_0+2\pi)$.

Comment: @Sarah: I wrote yes to 'then, i have to put my $x_0$ to initial equation, right?', not to 'does it mean that x= -π/2?'

Comment: @mathlove: ok, i got it. so, i got that f(x0)=-π/4-9 and f(x0+2π)=-9-π-π/4

Comment: @Sarah: No. $f(x_0)=f(\pi/2)=\sin\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac 12\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}+10=11-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $f(x_0+2\pi)=f(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi)=f(\frac{5\pi}{2})=\sin\frac{5\pi}{2}-\frac 12\cdot\frac{5\pi}{2}+10=11-\frac{5}{4}\pi$.

Comment: yeah, 11, not 9. stupid mistake with sign. thank you.

Comment: @Sarah: You are welcome.

Comment: @mathlove -- sorry to revive this, but I don't understand the step between the last line and $\cos x_0=0.$ Could you please explain? Thanks

Comment: @WesleyLee: We have $x_0=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$. From $0\lt x_0\lt 2$, we want $k$ such that $0\lt \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\lt 2$, i.e. $0\lt \frac 12+k\lt\frac{2}{\pi}$. Now, $k$ has to be non-negative, and $k=0$ is sufficient since $\frac 12+0=\frac 24\lt\frac{2}{\pi}$. If $k\ge 1$, then $\frac 12+k\ge \frac 12+1\gt 1=\frac 22\gt\frac{2}{\pi}$. So, we have $k=0$ and $x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @mathlove -- Thanks for answering. I'm so sorry but I wasn't clear enough, I meant the step right before $\cos x_0=0$, the last line of the calculation with the tangent lines. No matter how I reorganize the equation I'm unable to arrive at $\cos x_0=0$. I've been stuck in this for hours.

Comment: @mathlove -- nevermind, I've got it. Thanks!